# How to remove specific noise from image with OpenCV

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing, noise

How I can remove this noise (rectangle 2x2px) from binary image?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problems exactly are you having?

Comment: Just keep the biggest black connected component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Median filtering (`cv::medianBlur()`) / morphology operations (`cv::morphologyEx()`, you need `opening`, I believe) are often used for your case - they enable cleaning out the isolated pixels. See more in [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/dbe/tutorial_opening_closing_hats.html).

Answer (score 2):

Both @melodisease and @Jazz suggested reasonable solutions. If you plan to go for connected components and to select those larger than a specific area, don't use `findContours()`. Use a recent OpenCV and go for [`cv::connectedComponentsWithStats()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gae57b028a2b2ca327227c2399a9d53241). You'll find it *much* faster.

Full disclosure: I contributed the algorithm...

Answer (score 1):

use `findContours` function to remove small noisy components from your image based on area.